# Appending random name to file upload

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

I'm saving files along with user data to a table on a database. Right now, everything works perfectly, except that I can't find an efficient way to append a random name to the uploaded files name. In which the file is renamed for viewing and on the database. Here's what I have working at the moment.

```
<?php 

 $target = "files/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

 $title=$_POST['title'];
 $description=$_POST['description'];
 $username=$_POST['username'];
 $image=$_POST['image'];
 $timestamp=$_POST['timestamp'];
 $file=($_FILES['file']['name']);
 $from=$_POST['from'];
 $button_id=$_POST['button_id'];

 mysql_connect("", "", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `client_files` VALUES ('$title', '$description','$username', '$image', '$timestamp', '$file', '$from', '$button_id')") ;

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 
  echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

What would be the best way to append a random name to the uploaded file?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried the following, in which I think will be the solution...

```
 $file = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . '.' . substr(strrchr(($_FILES['file']['name']), '.'), 1);
```

I'm able to get the name of the file renamed to a random string on the DB, but unable to update it once it passes through to the folder. I'm thinking maybe, if I pass it through the target first, it will change both the DB and file on the server. Though I tried the following,

```
$target = "files/"; $target = tempnam($target, "");
```

But the file becomes broken and unreadable..

Comment: you can try to use tempnam function.

$target = "files/"; 
$target = tempnam($target, "");

Comment: How would I get that to adhere to data stored in the DB? Putting tempnam with $file=($_FILES['file']['name']); ass well?

Answer (score 0):

You can append a unique random number to existing name.
Try below code

```
$target = "files/"; 
$random = rand(0,9999);
$filename = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

$target = $target.$random.$filename ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the $file variable to the random name you want, also you might want to keep the file extension in place. I use the following code

```
$file = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . '.' . substr(strrchr(($_FILES['file']['name']), '.'), 1);
```

**Moving and Saving the file.**

```
$target = $target . $file; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);
```

You can rename the file while uploading.

Comment: All of you guys, thank you! I've tried a lot of these, but I think I might have to explain more in my question. I'm able to get the file to rename in the DB, but not in the folder on the server. Check out my updated when you get a chance.

Comment: You should move the file with the new generated name so that it will be same in the database and also in the server